# How to make Windows Emacs ^C^C run script, instead of just sending buffer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, emacs

Having made as small `print('Hello')` in Windows Emacs, I try to run this from within Emacs, using first ^C^P to make Python interpreter, and then ^C^C to run then code.  However this only says:

> send: print...

But it does not run the code.  How to make Windows Emacs run the code also ?

Version info:

- GNU Emacs: 25.0.50.1
- Python: 3.5.2

Comment: I'm guessing maybe the line endings need to be configured for M$-DOG. For the record, which Emacs version and Python mode are you using?

Comment: @tripleee M$-DOG? what are you a juvenile? ["I stab at thee"](https://www.penny-arcade.com/comic/2002/07/22)

Comment: @tripleee: Added version info; how do I configure line endings?

Comment: What's the value of `py-shell-name` and does the file it specifies exist on your system?  Also `py-version` in Emacs is what I tried to ask for, not the actual Python interpreter's version (though that's tangentially informative as well).

Comment: @tripleee: Using `C-h v {var} RET` to inspect the variables, neither `py-shell-name` nor `py-version` have a value.

Comment: Then what *is* the Python mode you are using? Maybe it was renamed (I only have Emacs 24 here) but the fact is there are multiple Python modes for Emacs.

Comment: @tripleee: I am note aware of what Python mode I am using... but Emacs recognizes the files as Python.  There is a Python menu in Emacs, with e.g. "Skeleton" item, but no "About Python" with info about mode.

Comment: `C-h m` documents the active modes.

Comment: @tripleee: Looks like `python.el` defines the mode.